# What Hebrew language Mishna do you recommend?

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, mishna

I like Koren Publishing, and I noticed they have Bartenura and Kav V'Naki edition. I want to practice my Hebrew. I like a clean visual design, but also portability. What should I purchase? Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Tim and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: One thing that might help us help you is if you specify a few criteria which are important to you when deciding between editions. Since we don't know you, it is hard to make a recommendation otherwise

Comment: I recommend something like [this](https://www.nehora.com/mishnayos-in-one-volume/). Portability, clean layout, all Hebrew, and only the Mishnayot, no commentary, etc.

Comment: Who voted to close, and why? This is pretty much the definition of a product recommendation question!

Comment: Can you please clarify the import of "I want to practice my Hebrew"? Do you mean that your Hebrew is weak so you want a bilingual Mishnah? Or that you want to practice your modern Hebrew so you want a Mishnah with commentary in modern Hebrew? Or simply that you want to read Mishnah-era Hebrew so you need neither a translation not a commentary?

Comment: Koren is the beautiful I know.

Comment: You could go the digital route and use safaria: https://www.sefaria.org/

Comment: To the close voters: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4375/

Comment: Since this pops up today, a few days before its launch, I would note Koren just came out with the Steinsaltz Mishna. It is beautiful but not portable. https://korenpub.co.il/products/mishna-mevoeret

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [this](http://shops.hidabroot.org/pl_product~11300003~10~72.htm) set.

But I use [this](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/65142/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1-%D7%9E%D7%97-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) in everyday practice, because of a very good and large font, not tiring for eyes. You can take one in the pocket

I love it; it is clear and not expensive.

Koren have beautiful font, a good quality of paper, but is expensive.

Kav Vnaki is expensive and the Bartenura is little and not easy to read. The Kav Vnaki perush is not useful at all in my humble experience.

Comment: I like anything from אור דוד! :D Great הוצאת ספרים

Comment: Note that Koren is easy to get in Israel and the US, they sell online and in most Judaica stores. The Kav vNaki edition starts at 20$ for the complete small set ([here](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/mishna-sdura/kav-v-naki-edition/he-koren-mishna-sdura-kav-v-naki-edition.html))

Comment: To buy a microscope to read it is expensive

Comment: @kouty this is really funny. My kind of humor.

Answer (score 1):

How about the classic Kehati-version. See for example here ([Hebrew](https://www.eichlers.com/religious/name-sku-33.html))
[image]

And then there is a phenomenal [Artscroll Hebrew version](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422625811.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oz Vehadar recently released a "Mishnayos Oz Vehadar 15 Volume set" set ([link here](https://ozvehadar.us/mishnayos-oz-vehadar-15-volume-set/)).

I just bought it and it's excellent.

Comment: Seems excessive for what they're looking for